# Bigcommerce API empty response from server with sequential requests

Tags: curl, bigcommerce

I am attempting to first update a brand, then create a product using the Bigcommerce API. I am doing so with the following code:

```
Bigcommerce::updateBrand(48, ['name'=>'Del Sol']);
echo "Brand Updated";
Bigcommerce::createProduct(['name'=>'New Test'.rand(), 'weight'=>3, 'price'=>3, 'availability'=>'available', 'categories'=>[1582], 'type'=>'physical']);
echo "Product Created";
```

This results in an `Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError` being returned, with the message `Empty reply from server`.

If I run either of the commands above by themselves, the request succeeds. If I switch the order of the commands, so that the product is created and then the brand is updated, both requests succeed. However, when I run them as shown, the `updateBrand` command works correctly, but the `createProduct` command hangs for a while and then throws the `Bigcommerce\Api\NetworkError`.

Why would this be happening?